# Displaying video texture on object but hiding background colour/transparency?

Tags: 3d-view

Say I want to apply a video texture of a bunny to a plane. The video is of a bunny tilting his head back and forth in a stationary position, and the rest of the background is a solid colour or transparent.

What I would want is to apply just the bunny part to a 3d object to display it upon render.

So atm I have say a cube, I can apply a material and then texture as video. And display the video on a single or all faces of the cube. But I want the background around the bunny deleted and a cookiee cutter effect done to the object if possible so it doesn't overlap other objects, so just the bunny is being shown up. How should I go back doing this?

My end intent is to apply a particle effect to text that disappears. And have the particles be the video of the bunny applied to them. So as you can imagine I can't have black background overlapping particles so close together.

I mean the obvious solution would be to just sculpt the bunny in 3d and make it itself the particle object. But I don't know how to do that kinnda stuff....so an oddly shaped object with 2d plastered image on it is my intent atm.

Comment: If I follow you right, you want to texture say a plane with an alpha-layered video, so the 'Bunny' is the only thing visible and without a background.  The plane is then used as a particle 'Object' to be sprinkled or whatever onto text?  If this is the case then yes it can be done easily enough once you've added the alpha layer to the video.  To do this your bunny will need to be filmed against a green screen or 'roto scoped' I think the term is, where you mask out the bunny in each frame.  That's not all that hard either but very time consuming.  Cycling a few frames is easier.

Comment: Even if I have the bunny itself with transparency for the background in say a 1080p video. How do I handle the rest of the problem? Will the transparency itself be applied over the plane? So if I put a transparent image over a plane the plane basically disappears? cause I want multiple of these planes overlapping afterall. And what do you mean by cycling a few frames is easier?

Comment: Answering your last question first - Cycling means just having a few motion frames of the bunny and repeating them over and over automatically.  The first Question - Once you have an alpha layered bunny on one plane, that can be placed overlapping another plane without affecting it at all.  I'm speaking here from what you'll see in the 3D viewport and rendering that out in OpenGL.  If you intend using nodes in the compositor or Cycles, that's a different approach altogether and one I'm not all that familiar with. It will also take considerably longer to render each time.

Comment: Ok I'll try that then. Is there an easy way to turn colour (like black) to alpha for a video (or a video I turn into an image sequence)? Like say My bunny is a solid white single colour with no features on a black background. Or do I have to go "the green screen removal" via nodes approach (which is very cumbersome) (or the masking approach as you stated which also is cumbersome)?

Comment: No, the black background should get you there ok, turn it into a transparent plane with the bunny doing it's thing.   You will need a node setup as for a green screen but I can give you snapshots as to how to do that.   I'd probably make that a separate project - make the video first, then use it to texture your plane(s).